# How to use Valgrind with Meson?

Tags: c++, valgrind, meson-build

```
project('testproject', 'cpp')

src = ['a.cpp', 'b.cpp']

executable('test', src)
```

What is the simplest way to build my executable with Valgrind using Meson build system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

valgrind is a dynamic analysis tool, there is no need to recompile it specially for valgrind.

For example, you can do:

> valgrind ls

and valgrind will run and analyse the ls command.

Note that it is however recommended to compile with debugging information, as otherwise the error reports of valgrind will not be very understandable.

An introduction on how to use valgrind is available in http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/QuickStart.html

Comment: I see, I let myself get confused by a certain example command in the guide, `valgrind --leak-check=yes myprog arg1 arg2`, in which I mistook arg1 and arg2 as being source files, and assumed that the command was being used to compile the program. A good reminder to always double check! Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4):

Just for completeness, wanted to note that **valgrind** can be used as wrapper in **meson** command line, for example

```
$ meson test --wrap='valgrind --leak-check=full --error-exitcode=1' testname
```

or

```
$ meson test --wrap='valgrind --tool=helgrind -v --error-exitcode=1' testname
```

which can be combined with other test options, e.g.

```
$ meson test --wrap='valgrind --leak-check=full --error-exitcode=1' testname --repeat=100
```

Check [this page](https://mesonbuild.com/Unit-tests.html#other-test-options) of reference manual.